# Ensuring a matched string contains at least one uppercase character

Tags: regex

Given a string

"This my uppercase test url (http://www.somedomain.com/some/Path). This my lowercase test url (http://www.somedomain.com/some/path)"

I have a regex that will find the urls:

```
\(http://www.somedomain.com/(.*?)\)
```

Can I amend this to only return the url if it contains an uppercase character in the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a positive lookahead to check the uppercase character:

```
(?=\S*[A-Z])\(http://www.somedomain.com/(.*?)\)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It'll make sure there's at least one uppercase character in the string.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gJ6lL3)

---

If you want to make sure that the 'check' remains within the brackets, you can use this:

```
\((?=[^)\s]*[A-Z])http://www.somedomain.com/(.*?)\)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aJ7qM0)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work if the url was immediately followed by an uppercase character (see http://regex101.com/r/pZ9oZ4). I've amended to http://regex101.com/r/tV0jD2

Comment: @JamesHay Woah, I've never used characters directly put aside of parentheses... But that's fixable. edited my answer.